# Discovering services via Bonjour on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, bonjour

I'm having trouble understanding privacy constraints for local network service discovery using Bonjour on iOS 14. Here is what I found:

1. Using NetServiceBrowser, I'm able to discover services using:
   `browser.searchForServices(ofType: "_services._dns-sd._udp", inDomain: "local.")`
   I have to add a couple of keys to .plist file, but it works.
2. However, if I turn to `NWBrowser`, and try to run the same request, I get an error:

```
    nw_browser_fail_on_dns_error_locked [B1] Invalid meta query type specified. 
    nw_browser_start_dns_browser_locked failed: BadParam(-65540)
```

I gather, this means I need the multicast entitlement.

Now, the question is, why would I go through all the trouble of requesting multicast entitlement from Apple, if I just can use `NetServiceBrowser` instead of `NWBrowser`? Doesn't `NetServiceBrowser` defeat the purpose of obtaining multicast entitlement?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/kdnsserviceerr_badparam) this error means that you passed an invalid value to `NWBrowser` - most probably it's the format of the service you're trying to discover.

You haven't posted your `NWBrowser` code, but for example, a wrong formatted service such as `_example_.tcp` would probably result in the error you're seeing. Make sure it is in the correct format, which should be something like `_example._tcp.`.

Another thing you need to do is modify your Info.plist file and add two keys:

- `Bonjour Services` - this is an array, the first item should be the service you're trying to discover, in my example, it is `_example._tcp.`
- `Privacy - Local Network Usage Description` - that one takes an explanation text which will be shown to the user the moment you start discovery with `NWBrowser`.

Now regarding the entitlement you mentioned: it is only needed for apps that scan for *all* services on the network and not a specific one like in your case. I encourage you to watch [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10110/), which explains everything I wrote here.

Lastly, why should you use `NWBrowser` over `NetServiceBrowser`? That's a very good question which I'm also trying to figure out the answer for

Answer (score 0):

1. The multicast entitlement is only required if you're scanning for all services. If you're scanning for a specific service - you don't need it

In iOS15 - if you do not have the entitlement you can not do

```
browser.searchForServices(ofType: "_services._dns-sd._udp", inDomain: "local.")
```

2. The reason to use NWBrowser is that it is the new api - NetServiceBrowser is deprecated. At some point - Apple will (probably) simply remove NetServiceBrowser. It's pretty deeply ingrained in a lot of software though - so I don't see them removing it any time soon.

NWBrowser is a somewhat easier API to use as far as straightforward browsing goes.

Note though - that if you want to resolve a service to get an IP address, you'll need to use NetService anyway...